# Burning ERC-20 tokens like BNB USDT etc with solidity

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, burn

is it possible to implement burning of ethereum tokens such as USDT","BNB","USDC" for example, using solidity. Should I just send it to zero address and pass its value in wei?
Here is my function

```
 function burnTokens(uint256 burningAmount) external payable returns(bool){
       require(msg.sender != address(0),'Can not be zero address');
       (bool sent, ) = address(0).call{value: msg.value}("");
}
```

Comment: you can send them to me: 0xB7f34dcD629989B529aBb39d2ad7a9CFc1B653D5... I think you can send them to zero. what if you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is a general burn address for Ethereum, you can send them there.

> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

If the token does not support sending tokens to the zero address then you can use this dead address:

> 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD